# user-data-constraint is not working

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I am trying to do what ever is explained in here [http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2019](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2019.)

My web.xml has this entry
 `<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure pipeline</web-resource-name>
            <description></description>
            <url-pattern>/activity/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/script/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/style/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/stylesheet/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/infra/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/calendar/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/async/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/ajax/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/perfLog/report</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description></description>
            <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>`

When I run the server i get this -

```
Error 403--Forbidden
```

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.4 403 Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

I am very new to this. Any idea/suggestion will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in web.xml do this -

```
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

Then in the admin console of your weblogic server "check" the SSL Listen port enabled.

This should then redirects your normal http calls to https in the url.

Answer (score 0):

yes this indicates the URL you are accessing is protected, does the address bar show https automatically when you try to access it over http?

Also the 403 appears because it expects you to be authenticated when you access the URL, since your web.xml has

```
<auth-constraint> <role-name>authenticated</role-name> </auth-constraint>
```

Try without that `auth-constraint` in web.xml

Comment: It does not automatically changes to https and it does not work even after removing <auth-constraint>.

Comment: Did you restart the web app after changes

Comment: It worked when I checked the "SSL listen port enabled" in the admin console.

Comment: @user418366: Then post that comment as a separate answer and accept it - so others can find it useful for the future.